# Alguien me puede explicar respecto al orden de la salida del siguiente programa

Tags: c++, c

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MiClase {
 private:
  int dato;

 public:
  MiClase();                   // constructor por defecto
  MiClase(int);                // constructor común
  MiClase(const MiClase&);     // constructor por copia
  ~MiClase();                  // destructor
  MiClase operator=(MiClase);  // operador de asignación

  MiClase funcion3(MiClase);
  MiClase funcion4(MiClase);
};
```

La implementación de las operaciones de la clase `MiClase` es la siguiente:

```cpp
MiClase::MiClase() {
  dato = 0;
  cout << "Soy el constructor por defecto ";
  cout << " Mi Dato es " << dato << '\n';
}

MiClase::MiClase(int i) {
  dato = i;
  cout << "Soy el constructor comun ";
  cout << " Mi dato es " << dato << '\n';
}

MiClase::MiClase(const MiClase &m) {
  dato = m.dato;
  cout << "Soy el constructor de copia ";
  cout << " Mi Dato es " << dato << '\n';
}

MiClase::~MiClase() {
  cout << "Soy el destructor ";
  cout << " Mi dato era " << dato << '\n';
}

MiClase MiClase::operator=(MiClase m) {
  dato = m.dato;
  cout << "Soy el operador de asignacion" << '\n';
  return *this;
}

MiClase MiClase::funcion3(MiClase m) {
  MiClase local;
  local.dato = m.dato * dato;
  cout << "Esta es la funcion 3 " << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << " El dato del objeto local es " << local.dato << '\n';
  return local;
}

MiClase MiClase::funcion4(MiClase m) {
  MiClase local(MiClase(10));
  cout << "Esta es la funcion 4 " << '\n';
  return local;
}
```

El siguiente programa principal crea diferentes instancias de clase `MiClase` e invoca  operaciones sobre ellas.

```cpp
int main() {
  MiClase m1(10);
  MiClase m2 = m1;
  MiClase m3 = 30;
  cout << '\n';
  cout << "antes de la asignacion" << '\n';
  m2 = m1;
  cout << "despues de la asignacion" << '\n';
  cout << '\n';
  cout << "Antes de invocar a funcion3" << '\n';
  m2 = m1.funcion3(m3);
  cout << "Despues de invocar a funcion3" << '\n';
  cout << '\n';
  cout << "Antes de invocar a funcion4" << '\n';
  m2 = m1.funcion4(m3);
  cout << "Despues de invocar a funcion4" << '\n';
  cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

A continuación, se reproduce la salida producida por el programa y se comentan algunas de las invocaciones.

> Soy el constructor comun Mi dato es 10 linea 3
> Soy el constructor de copia Mi Dato es 10 linea 4
> Soy el constructor comun Mi dato es 30 linea 5
> Antes de la asignación

**Primera duda**

Cuando se hace `m2 = m1` , se invoca a la operación de asignación que tiene como parametro a "m", como se está pasando a "m1", se copia el objeto m1 en m, o sea, que se llama a el constructor de copia y se imprime la línea:

> soy el constructor por copia mi dato es 10

Luego se sigue en el cuerpo de la operacion de asignación, por lo que se imprime la siguiente linea:

> Soy el operador de asignacion

Hasta aquí entiendo. Ahora saltamos más abajo y vamos a la invocación `m2 = m1.funcion3(m3);` la `funcion3` recibe a `m3` , por lo tanto, como la `funcion3` tiene en el cabezal al objeto `m` , pasado por valor, se copia a `m3` en `m` , por lo que se llama al constructor por copia y se imprime la siguiente linea:

> Soy el constructor de copia Mi Dato es 30

( `m` es param. formal de `funcion3` ) luego volvemos a la `funcion3` , se crea el objeto "local". Como no se le pasa ningún parámetro se invoca al constructor por defecto e imprime la linea:

> Soy el constructor por defecto Mi Dato es 0 (constr. de local)

Luego volvemos a la `funcion3` y al objeto local se le asigna un valor que equivale a 300.

Luego imprime

> Esta es la funcion 3
> El dato del objeto local es 300

Y hace dentro de la funcion3, `return(local)` . Este objeto local se está devolviendo a la llamada `m2 = m1.funcion3(m3)` , por lo que quedaría algo así, como `m2 = local` , lo cual es una asignación, entonces, según entiendo, cuando vamos a la operación de asignación, ésta recibe como parametro a "local" y tiene que copiar a "local" en "m" que es su parametro formal. Por lo que entiendo que debería imprimirse:

> soy el constructor de copia mi dato es 300

Y luego:

> soy el operador de asignación

Sin embargo, en la salida aparece al revés, aparece así:

> Soy el operador de asignacion
> Soy el constructor de copia Mi Dato es 300

m (de operator=) es copia de local#

**¿Qué es lo que estoy entendiendo mal?**

Omití partes del código innecesarias, la duda está en la llamada a `funcion3` . Apliqué el mismo razonamiento que cuando se hizo la asignacion, `m2 = m1` , solo que en la `funcion3` las sentencias que se imprimen son en orden inverso al que mi razonamiento me indica; ¿por qué será?

---

@abulafia tu respuesta está genial pero yo sigo sin entender. Je! perdón.
En la función3, en determinado momento se hace "return(local)" , a donde se devuelve "local"? acá : m2 = local, porque la llamada era m2=m1.funcion3(m3), entonces queda algo asi como m2=local. esto es una asignación? supongamos que si.
entonces me dirijo al metodo de la operación de asignación, que tiene como parametro formal a "m"
como tiene como parametro formal a "m" yo entiendo que tiene que copiar "local" en "m" por lo que invocaría al constructor de copia e imprimiria
"soy el constructor de copia mi dato es 300",
luego vuelvo a el cuerpo de la operacion de asignación y prosigo secuencialmente con las sentencias, dato=m.dato (m seria la copia de local)
y lo que viene despues es cout<<"soy el operador de asignación"
y luego "return(*this)".... no sé si mas o menos se entiende cómo estoy razonando. Quizá el problema es que estoy razonandolo mal, o no estoy entendiendo la parte de la creación de objetos temporales, yo voy secuencialmente.
Gracias de todos modos!!

[image: imagen explicativa de la situación que genera confusión]

Comment: Por favor dale formato adecuado a tu pregunta, no indentes como código texto que no lo es

Comment: Si identas correctamente el texto y el código, no habrá necesidad de escribir todo ese texto dummy que has puesto

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ya arregle todo lo que pude.. ahora, usa e boton [edit] y pone puntos, comas y lo que haga falta donde corresponde...

Comment: He intentado mejorar la legibilidad dando un formato diferente a lo que son salidas del programa. No obstante sigue siendo muy difícil de leer. Te sugiero editar el código para indentarlo correctamente, y resumir la explicación de tu razonamiento.

Comment: @matiasAndersen He editado mi respuesta para aclarar un poco mejor lo que está pasando. Vuelve a leerla a ver si aún mantienes tu duda.

Comment: Hola @matias, formateé el código. Revisa e intenta mejorarla. Solo edité hasta donde pude hacerlo.

Comment: En la edición, la última parte no la toqué porque es prácticamente _imposible_ editarla sin la intervención del autor de la pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que puede ayudar a aclarar las cosas el que en los mensajes que vas imprimiendo para depuración incluyas el imprimir el valor de `this`. Por ejemplo:

```cpp
MiClase::MiClase(){
  dato = 0;
  cout << "Soy el constructor por defecto " << this;
  cout << " Mi Dato es " << dato << '\n';
}
```

Y así con el resto de funciones que se implementan. El valor de `this` es único para cada uno de los objetos que se van creando, lo que nos permite ver en los mensajes sobre qué objetos están actuando estas operaciones. Así, por ejemplo, el primer mensaje que veríamos al ejecutar el programa sería:

```html
Soy el constructor comun 0x7fff785fee68 Mi dato es 10
```

El número `0x7fff785fee68` es la dirección del objeto que está siendo creado. De algún modo podemos pensar en ese número como una especie de "identificador único" del objeto. Cuando más adelante veamos aparecer de nuevo ese mismo número en otro mensaje, sabremos que está actuando sobre el mismo objeto.

Por otro lado, comparando con el código, sabemos que el primer objeto en ser creado es `m1`, por lo que podemos establecer la asociación y decir que el número `0x7fff785fee68` **es** (en cierto sentido) el objeto `m1`.

Ejecutemos el programa completo y veamos qué salida produce (voy a detener la salida después de que vuelva la función `funcion3()`, ya que esa es la duda que nos ocupa):

```html
Soy el constructor comun 0x7fff785fee68 Mi dato es 10
Soy el constructor de copia 0x7fff785fee60 Mi Dato es 10
Soy el constructor comun 0x7fff785fee50 Mi dato es 30

antes de la asignacion
Soy el constructor de copia 0x7fff785fee40 Mi Dato es 10
Soy el operador de asignacion0x7fff785fee60
Soy el constructor de copia 0x7fff785fee48 Mi Dato es 10
Soy el destructor 0x7fff785fee48 Mi dato era 10
Soy el destructor 0x7fff785fee40 Mi dato era 10
despues de la asignacion

Antes de invocar a funcion3
Soy el constructor de copia 0x7fff785fee28 Mi Dato es 30
Soy el constructor por defecto 0x7fff785fee30 Mi Dato es 0
Esta es la funcion 3 
     El dato del objeto local es 300
Soy el operador de asignacion0x7fff785fee60
Soy el constructor de copia 0x7fff785fee38 Mi Dato es 300
Soy el destructor 0x7fff785fee38 Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor 0x7fff785fee30 Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor 0x7fff785fee28 Mi dato era 30
Despues de invocar a funcion3
```

Ahora voy a reescribir "a mano" esa salida cambiando los números misteriosos como `0x7fff785fee68` por el objeto que yo sé que es en realidad. Por ejemplo, ya vimos que `0x7fff785fee68` es el objeto `m1`. Cuando vuelva a aparecer ese número lo cambiaré por `(m1)` para que los mensajes sean más fáciles de leer y de seguir.

De vez en cuando aparecen números nuevos, que no son ni `m1` ni `m2` ni `m3`. Son objetos temporales que C++ va creando para poder hacer el paso de parámetros, las copias, asignaciones, etc. Cuando aparezca un número de estos lo llamaré `(tmp1)` o `(tmp2)`, etc, según vayan siendo creados.

El resultado de "traducir" de este modo la salida queda así:

```html
Soy el constructor comun (m1) Mi dato es 10
Soy el constructor de copia (m2) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el constructor comun (m3) Mi dato es 30

antes de la asignacion
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp1) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el operador de asignacion(m2)
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp2) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el destructor (tmp2) Mi dato era 10
Soy el destructor (tmp1) Mi dato era 10
despues de la asignacion

Antes de invocar a funcion3
Soy el constructor de copia (m) Mi Dato es 30
Soy el constructor por defecto (local) Mi Dato es 0
Esta es la funcion 3 
     El dato del objeto local es 300
Soy el operador de asignacion(m2)
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp3) Mi Dato es 300
Soy el destructor (tmp3) Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor (local) Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor (m) Mi dato era 30
Despues de invocar a funcion3
```

Vamos entonces a estudiar esta salida.

### Creación inicial de objetos

```html
Soy el constructor comun (m1) Mi dato es 10
Soy el constructor de copia (m2) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el constructor comun (m3) Mi dato es 30
```

No hay misterios aquí, cada objeto es creado en su propia dirección.

### Asignación `m2=m1`

Aquí pasa una cosa que puede parecer sorprendente:

```html
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp1) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el operador de asignacion(m2)
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp2) Mi Dato es 10
Soy el destructor (tmp2) Mi dato era 10
Soy el destructor (tmp1) Mi dato era 10
```

Vemos que en primer lugar se saca una copia de `m1` a un objeto temporal (`tmp1`), y es ese objeto el que se pasa al operador de asignación. El operador de asignación parece que crea internamente una copia más (`tmp2`) que usa para copiar el dato hipotéticamente en `m2`. Después los dos objetos temporales son destruidos.

Hay **dos copias temporales** y por eso el operador de copia es llamado dos veces. Estas dos copias ocurren debido a la implementación que has hecho del operador de asignación, que básicamente es:

```
MiClase MiClase::operator=(MiClase m){
  dato = m.dato;
  return *this;
}
```

Vemos que la función recibe `m` por valor, y al retornar `*this`, el retorno es también por valor. De modo que es necesario invocar al operador de copia para copiar el argumento `m2` en el parámetro `m` y otra vez al operador de copia para el valor retornado `*this` (con el cual después no se hace nada).
De algún modo (así lo interpreto yo), la asignación ha creado un objeto temporal "a la derecha del signo igual" para copiar `m1` en él y otro "a la izquierda del signo igual" para pasárselo al constructor de copia de `m2`.

Por tanto, lo que llamé `(tmp1)` es en realidad `m` y lo que llamé `(tmp2)` es el valor retornado por el operador =.

### Asignación `m2=m1.funcion3(m3)`

Aquí la secuencia de mensajes cuenta otra historia:

```html
Soy el constructor de copia (m) Mi Dato es 30
Soy el constructor por defecto (local) Mi Dato es 0
Esta es la funcion 3 
     El dato del objeto local es 300
Soy el operador de asignacion(m2)
Soy el constructor de copia (tmp3) Mi Dato es 300
Soy el destructor (tmp3) Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor (local) Mi dato era 300
Soy el destructor (m) Mi dato era 30
```

La cosa empieza como cabe esperar, creando un objeto nuevo que he llamado `(m)` pues es el parámetro formal de la función `funcion3()`. Luego se crea otro que tiene que ser la variable local. Pero cuando vamos a la asignación vemos que **en este caso sólo se crea un objeto temporal**. Ese objeto corresponde al `return *this`, pero falta el constructor de copia que sería necesario para pasar el parámetro a `operator=(m)`.

**Conclusión**

Así pues no es que salgan los mensajes en orden inverso a como te esperabas, sino que uno de los que te esperabas no está. Esperabas esto:

```
[..omitido..]
Esta es la funcion 3 
     El dato del objeto local es 300
Soy el constructor de copia Mi Dato es 300 <----- ESTE EN REALIDAD NO SALE
Soy el operador de asignacion
Soy el constructor de copia Mi Dato es 300 <----- ESTE SI
```

El primero sería para pasar el valor `local` retornado por `funcion3()` como parámetro a `operator=()`, y ese **no se produce**. El resto ya es normal.

¿Por qué no se produce esa copia en este caso? Se trata sin duda de una optimización del compilador, pero no puedo darte más detalles al respecto pues depende de cómo esté implementado.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, yo espero que salga en ese orden. En las notas de facultad está en este orden con la siguiente justificiación :
[omito partes anteriores]
"el dato del objeto local es 300''
"soy el operador de asignacion''
"soy el constructor de copia mi dato es 300'' y en la justificacion que aparece al costado de esta salida dice (m de operador= es copia de local)
entonces lo que yo entiendo es que debió haber hecho la copia enseguida entró al cabezal de la función y no después de la frase "soy el operador de asignación". Discúlpame por lo terco.

Comment: Entendi que m no copia a local y por eso no se produce la primera salida 
"soy el constructor por copia mi dato es 300"
pero despues de la salida 
"soy el operador de asignación" mi duda es, dentro del cuerpo de la operación de asignación, cual es la sentencia que invoca al constructor de copia para que si salga 
''soy el constructor por copia mi dato es 300'' 
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: @matiasandersen Es el `return `*this` que retorna (por valor) el objeto, y del que por tanto hay que hacer copia.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de todos modos me gustaria insertar la imagen donde esta explicado porque por lo que entiendo por tu explicación, el material de la facultad estaría mal, y eso es bastante poco común. pero bueno . . . No sé insertar imagen.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y pinchar en el botón "Insertar imagen" (o pulsar Ctrl+G). En un comentario en cambio no puedes insertar imágenes, pero sí puedes subir la imagen a un servicio como imgur e inertar el enlace en el comentario.

Comment: Allí pude insertar un segmento de la imagen a la que hice referencia mas arriba. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @matiasandersen Ya veo... pues me ratifico en mi opinión de que el constructor de copia que se está invocando ahi es el causado por el `return` y no por el paso de parámetro (de lo contrario ese mensaje habría aparecido antes de "Soy el operador de asignación" como tú pensabas). Se puede verificar esta hipótesis (y lo he hecho) si en el constructor de copia imprimes el valor de `&m`, que es el objeto copiado. Entonces se ve que el mensaje indica que está copiando a una variable temporal el valor de `m2` (como corresponde al `return *this`) en vez de `local` (como explica tu imagen)

Comment: Hace años deje la carrera y pretendo retomarla, hay cosas que no tengo claras, se que *this sería ''lo apuntado por this'' siendo this la dirección de memoria del objeto. 
Pero que sería &m? cuando en un cabezal ponemos & estamos pasando el parametro por referencia y eso permitía modificar el parámetro a diferencia de cuando lo pasamos por valor.  entonces ''this'' y ''&m'' no serían lo mismo?
Ahora, en definitiva, que es lo correcto lo que está en la imagen o lo que tu has explicado aqui? Me cuesta un poco entender, es mucha información junta. Saludos y nuevamente gracias.

Comment: `m` es una copia de un dato que ha recibido la función como parámetro. `&m` dentro de la función sirve para obtener la dirección de memoria en que está esa copia. Cuando se pasa por referencia (poniendo `&m` en la declaración) no hay copia, sino el objeto original, así que imprimiendo `&m` en ese caso verías la dirección del objeto original que has pasado como parámetro. `this` y `&m` no son lo mismo  porque `this` es la dirección del objeto cuyo método de asignación se está ejecutando, mientras que `&m` es la dirección del objeto recibido como parámetro.

Comment: En cuanto a qué explicación es la correcta, yo creo que la mía es correcta, al menos en base a lo que se ve cuando vas imprimiendo las direcciones de los objetos involucrados. Por otro lado la explicación de la imagen no puede ser correcta porque si lo fuera el mensaje "soy el constructor de copia" debería salir antes y no después del mensaje "soy el operador de asignación".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede aquí es que el programa está creando un objeto temporal. Es facil verlo aplicando un par de cambios en tu código:

```
MiClase::MiClase() {
  dato = 0;
  cout << "Soy el constructor por defecto\n";
  cout << "\tMi Dato es " << dato << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << (void*)this << '\n';
}

MiClase::MiClase(int i) {
  dato = i;
  cout << "Soy el constructor comun\n";
  cout << "\tMi dato es " << dato << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << (void*)this << '\n';
}

MiClase::MiClase(const MiClase &m) {
  dato = m.dato;
  cout << "Soy el constructor de copia\n";
  cout << "\tMi Dato es " << dato << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << (void*)this << ' ' << (void*)&m << '\n';
}

MiClase::~MiClase() {
  cout << "Soy el destructor\n";
  cout << "\tMi dato era " << dato << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << (void*)this << '\n';
}

MiClase MiClase::operator=(MiClase m) {
  dato = m.dato;
  cout << "Soy el operador de asignacion" << '\n';
  cout << '\t' << (void*)this << ' ' << (void*)&m << '\n';
  return *this;
}
```

Ahora podemos ver las direcciones de memoria de los objetos involucrados en las diferentes operaciones.

Si ejecutamos el programa, obtendremos una salida como la siguiente:

```
Soy el constructor comun
    Mi dato es 10
    0x7ffd929337d8
Soy el constructor de copia
    Mi Dato es 10
    0x7ffd929337d0 0x7ffd929337d8

...

Antes de invocar a funcion3
Soy el constructor de copia
    Mi Dato es 30
    0x7ffd92933798 0x7ffd929337c0
Soy el constructor por defecto
    Mi Dato es 0
    0x7ffd929337a0
Esta es la funcion 3 
     El dato del objeto local es 300
Soy el operador de asignacion
    0x7ffd929337d0 0x7ffd929337a0
Soy el constructor de copia
    Mi Dato es 300
    0x7ffd929337a8 0x7ffd929337d0
Soy el destructor
    Mi dato era 300
    0x7ffd929337a8
Soy el destructor
    Mi dato era 300
    0x7ffd929337a0
Soy el destructor
    Mi dato era 30
    0x7ffd92933798
Despues de invocar a funcion3
```

De aquí sacamos las siguiente información:

- `m1` está en `0x7ffd929337d8`
- `m2` está en `0x7ffd929337d0`
- `local` está en la posición `0x7ffd929337a0`
- Se copia el contenido de `local` en `m2`, `0x7ffd929337a0` -> `0x7ffd929337d0`
- Se crea un nuevo objeto copia de `m2`. La dirección de este nuevo objeto es `0x7ffd929337a8`
- Se destruye este objeto recién creado.
- Limpieza del resto de variables

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Es culpa tuya, lo siento. La parte buena es que tiene una solución muy simple de aplicar.

El problema está aquí:

```
MiClase operator=(MiClase);
```

Este operador, en teoría, recibe **una copia** de un objeto de tipo `MiClase` y devuelve  **otra copia**. La copia que te está incordiando ahora mismo es la segunda. Si atendemos a la implementación de esta función tenemos lo siguiente:

```
MiClase MiClase::operator=(MiClase m) {
    dato = m.dato;
    cout << "Soy el operador de asignacion" << '\n';
    return *this;
}
```

Ese `return *this` está creando una copia de tu objeto actual. El famoso objeto `0x7ffd929337a8`. Como esta copia no se usa para nada, a continuación se destruye y el proceso continúa su camino.

Se puede ver más facil si separamos las operaciones:

```
MiClase MiClase::operator=(MiClase m) {
    dato = m.dato;
    cout << "Soy el operador de asignacion" << '\n';
    MiClase objeto0x7ffd929337a0 = *this;
    return objeto0x7ffd929337a0;
}
```

La solución es tan simple como devolver una referencia constante en vez de una copia de sí mismo. Tampoco estaría de más evitar la copia de `m`.

Piensa que hoy en día los compiladores son bastante listos y son capaces de aplicar muchísimas optimizaciones, algunas bastante salvajes. Sin embargo estas optimizaciones tienen sus limitaciones y el compilador, bajo ciertas circunstancias, puede optar por no aplicarlas (porque determine que no sea seguro, por ejemplo). Esto quiere decir que aunque en este caso concreto no se llegue a realizar la copia de `m`, con un par de cambios posteriores es posible que dejes de beneficiarte de la optimización y entonces estarías cargando con una absurda copia de objetos que realmente no necesitas.

Para más información sobre estas optimizaciones deberías buscar información sobre *Copy Elision* y sobre *Return Value Optimization*.

La función *corregida* debería lucir así:

```
MiClase const& MiClase::operator=(MiClase const& m);
```